# WPF Bindings to model properties in ViewModel [MVVM]

Tags: c#, wpf

Im working with multiple Languages in my Application.
Im trying to do this with the MVVM Pattern, which is new to me, so
I read Tutorials from CodeProject and Tutorialspoint.

Heres my Project Structure:

```
Model
 ConverterModel.cs
 LanguageModel.cs
ViewModel
 ConverterViewModel.cs
View
 ConverterView.xaml
  ConverterView.xaml.cs
MainWindow.xaml
 MainWindow.xaml.cs
```

I created a model for all the language strings I need:

```
internal class LanguageModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //GUI Language

    private string title;
    private string inputBtn;
    private string outputBtn;
    private string convertBtn;
    ...
    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return title;
        }

        set
        {
            if(title != value)
            {
                title = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Title");
            }

        }
    }


    public string InputBtn
    {
        get
        {
            return inputBtn;
        }

        set
        {
            if (inputBtn != value)
            {
                inputBtn = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("InputBtn");
            }
        }
    }

    public string OutputBtn
    {
        get
        {
            return outputBtn;
        }

        set
        {
            if (outputBtn != value)
            {
                outputBtn = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("OutputBtn");
            }
        }
    }

    public string ConvertBtn
    {
        get
        {
            return convertBtn;
        }

        set
        {
            if (convertBtn != value)
            {
                convertBtn = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ConvertBtn");
            }
        }
    }

   ...

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if(PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

}

Then I create an instance of that model in my ViewModel and fill it with the desired Data:

```
 internal class ConverterViewModel 
{
    internal Settings Settings{ get; set; }
    ConverterModel Model { get; set; } //where the Data Fill Method is located 
    internal LanguageModel LanguageModel { get; set; }
    String Title {get; set;} = "Banana"; //<-- this seems to work just fine

    internal ConverterViewModel()
    {
        Model = new ConverterModel();
        Settings = new Settings();
        if(Settings.Language == "")
        {
            Settings.Language = "English";
            //getLanguage
            Settings.Save();
        }
        this.LanguageModel = Model.SetLanguageModel(Settings.Language);
    }
```

Data Fill method in ConverterModel:

```
class ConverterModel
{
            internal LanguageModel SetLanguageModel(string language)
    {
        switch (language)
        {
            case "English":
                LanguageModel english = new LanguageModel()
                {
                    Title = "TitleSomething",
                    InputBtn = "Inputfile",
                    OutputBtn = "Outputfile",
                    ConvertBtn = "Convert",
                };
                return english;
            case "German":
                LanguageModel german = new LanguageModel()
                {
                    //Work in Progress
                };
                return german;
            case "French":
                LanguageModel french = new LanguageModel()
                {
                    //Work in Progress
                };
                return french;
            case "Italian":
                LanguageModel italian = new LanguageModel()
                {
                 //Work in Progress
                };
                return italian;
            default: return null;
        }

    }
}
```

I have my Bindings set like this.

MainWindow:

```
<Window x:Class="dta2pain.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:dta2pain"
    xmlns:view="clr-namespace:dta2pain.View"
    xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:dta2pain.ViewModel"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    Title="{Binding Title}" //<-- works
    Height="657" Width="910">
<Grid>
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModel:ConverterViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
    <view:ConverterView x:Name="ConverterViewControl">
        <view:ConverterView.DataContext>
            <viewModel:ConverterViewModel/>
        </view:ConverterView.DataContext>
    </view:ConverterView>
</Grid>
```

ConverterView :

```
<UserControl x:Class="dta2pain.View.ConverterView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:dta2pain.View"
         xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:dta2pain.ViewModel"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="657" d:DesignWidth="910"
         Title = "{Binding Path = Title}">
<Grid>
    <Menu HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="910" >

    </Menu>
    <Grid Margin="0,15,0,0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.5*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.75*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1.5*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.25*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image x:Name="LogoImg" Grid.Row="0" Source="../Images/mammutLogoTop1280.jpg" Margin="0"/>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="15,5,15,0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1.5*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="765*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="62*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="47*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBox x:Name="InputTxt" Template="{StaticResource TextBoxBaseControlTemplate}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,5,0" Height="30" FontSize="14" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" />
            <Button x:Name="InputBtn" Template="{StaticResource RoundCornerBtn}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5,0,0,0" Height="30" FontSize="14" Background="#FF006561" Foreground="White"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="{Binding LanguageModel.InputBtn}"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="OutputTxt" Template="{StaticResource TextBoxBaseControlTemplate}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,5,0" Height="30" FontSize="14" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
            <Button x:Name="OutputBtn" Template="{StaticResource RoundCornerBtn}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,0,0,0" Height="30" FontSize="14" Background="#FF006561" Foreground="White" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="{Binding LanguageModel.OutputBtn}"/>
            <Button x:Name="ConvertBtn" Template="{StaticResource RoundCornerBtn}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="0,7,0,6" FontSize="16" Background="#FF006561" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" Content="{Binding LanguageModel.ConvertBtn}"/>
        </Grid>            
</Grid>
```

I dont know whether I failed at setting my Bindings to access the Properties of the instance of LanguageModel 
Or the RaisePropertyChanged() Method is implemented in a wrong way.
I've tried setting my Bindings like this `Path= LanguageModel.Property` before. 
and I've tried to put the Model Properties in an Observable List and Iterating through it, which also didnt work.

Also, when I try to debug the programm and hover my mouse over the LangaugeModel Property the Debugger shuts down with a StackOverFlow Exception. 
Now From the Exception I guesssed that my program gets caught in a loop somewhere, but I couldnt find where.

I Hope this is detailed enough to understand my problem.(First Post)

Comment: Note that there exist projects that do localization in XAML markup (e.g. https://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com/). You don´t have to do it by yourself.

Comment: I remember that XAML works correctly only with public properties in public classes. Try removing the internal and setting all in public.

Comment: Just to be noticed: you could use resx files for your loalization

Comment: @CyberNiinja: You should not mess with such problems in your code. Just use the ways that are already implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that there exist projects that do localization in XAML markup (e.g. wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com). You don´t have to do it by yourself.

The strings are located in resx files:

- fallback language:  filename.resx
- german language: filename.de.resx
- french language: filename.fr.resx

Comment: I will try this.